# Changing the color in MathJax or MathML

Tags: mathjax, mathml

If I have an equation like ax+b and I want to be able to display these with the coefficients highlighted, I could write

MathJax:

```
\(\color{blue}{m}x+\color{red}{c}\)
```

MathML:

```
<math>
    <mi style="color: blue">m</mi>
    <mi>x</mi>
    <mo>+</mo>
    <mi style="color: red">c</mi>
</math>
```

If I want to change the colors of the MathML-code I can simply use class-tags for the coefficients

```
    <mi class="mColor">m</mi>
```

and I can use a simple jQuery script (.css()) to change the colour of this class. Is there a similar tool for MathJax? Something like

```
\color{$mColor}{m}
```

Which I can change with a jQuery script?

tldr:
Is there a script in JS/jQuery which lets me change the colour of a MathJax symbol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\(\class{mColor}{m}x+\class{cColor}{c}\)`.  This will produce

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <mi class="mColor">m</mi>
  <mi>x</mi>
  <mo>+</mo>
  <mi class="cColor">c</mi>
</math>
```

so that you can change the styling of those two classes as you normally would.